# How to convert an ArrayCollection to xmllistcollection or to xmllist

Tags: apache-flex

Is there anyway of type casting an ArrayCollection to xmllistcollection or to xmllist
or can we covert ArrayCollection to xmllistcollection or to xmllist?

Comment: Important question: What is in the ArrayCollection?  Are you just talking about putting XML nodes in the different collections?  Or are you talking about converting an XMLList to a collection of strongly typed objects?

Comment: You can't cast it, but you can convert it.  Can I ask what's the point of this?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any automatic way to do this.  The source behind an ArrayCollection and an XMLListCollection are very different.

Your best bet is to create an Object (or Objects) with properties that match data the XMLCollection then convert loop over the XMLListCollection and convert manually.

Answer (score 0):

See the link.
[URL](http://www.guiroo.com/2009/04/20/arraycollection-to-xml-in-actionscript3/)

I know this reply is too late. But I hope it may helpful for some others